# What's SQL equivalent of MySQL SHOW CRAETE TABLE query

Tags: mysql, sql, export

I have a remote SQL Server database that I don't want to copy because of it's size. I want to just remotely import it's creation query to duplicate it's structure locally.

I know there was a query for it but lost somewhere my book about it. I ask for name of that query method that I described. If got any questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: In SSMS, right click on the database, select tasks/generate scripts...

Comment: @adrianm I have only access to SQL console.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It's `SHOW CREATE TABLE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: Well I though it's for MSSQL as well, but it's not. MSSQL sucks in that way. Got any alternative for `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: You can use SMO with whatever your favorite interface for it is. I like to use powershell. Any way you use it, you'd use the Script() method on the Table object.